# Set Deafult Language for Code Engineering

Tags: enterprise-architect

May this is not the place to ask such a thing, but there are several experts here...

I cannot find the definition of default code engineering language in EA 12.
In previos releases it was under Tools -> Options, on the source code engineering tab:

[image]

Where it it hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAster eggs: Project | Settings | Project Options | Source Code Engineering |  (model specific)

I had to consult the help. This is really ridiculous how they hide menus in each release.